# Is there a ScalaTest Plugin for Eclipse Luna and Scala IDE Lithium?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala-ide, eclipse-luna

Trying to find the ScalaTest plugin for use with Eclipse Luna and Scala IDE for Eclipse 4.0.0 (aka Lithium). Currently using Milestone 2 of the Scala IDE for Eclipse Lithium plugin.

The ScalaTest plugin used to be part of the Scala IDE for Eclipse plugin (appeared on the list and you could check the box it to install--Scala IDE for Eclipse is supposed to be an ecosystem of plugins, ScalaTest being one of them). It doesn't appear to be there any more.

- It's not on the list,
- When I check "Installation Details" it doesn't appear either, and
- Test configurations don't appear under "Run As..."

But there is mention of Luna in the ScalaTest plugin Github site for the scalatest plugin (https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-eclipse-plugin), which is supposed to be part of the Scala IDE for Eclipse ecosystem.

The tests run fine from the SBT command line. So I know the ScalaTest jar file is in the classpath and is of a compatible version for my project. The ScalaTest jar file appears as an external jar file in my project in Eclipse, and the tests compile in Eclipse. Other Scala IDE for Eclipse functions seem to work correctly.

**System Configuration:**

- **Eclipse Version:** Luna (4.4.0),
- **Scala IDE for Eclipse Version:** Lithium 4.0.0 Milestone 2, for Luna and Scala 2.11.1 (download site http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/dev/site)
- **Java Version:** Java 1.8_05,
- **Scala Version:** 2.11.1,
- **Build Tool:** SBT 0.13.5, running under Java 1.8_05,
- **ScalaTest Version:** scalatest_2.11-2.2.0.jar (copied into the lib directory of my project)

My Eclipse project file is generated by SBT using the eclipse SBT command, and loaded into Eclipse using the standard "Import->Existing Projects Into Workspace..." method. The build.sbt file is a single line reading scalaVersion := "2.11.1".

Is there a ScalaTest plugin for Eclipse Luna and Scala IDE for Eclipse 4.0 (Lithium)? If so, where do I go about finding it?

Comment: Hi Jamie. Try dropping a mail at the [ScalaTest Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/scalatest-users). I'm sure Bill Venners or Chua Chee Seng will tell you the details, they are extremely responsive and help quite a lot. If not, I owe you a beer :-) You could also contact them on Twitter.

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the lack of ScalaTest support in Scala IDE for Eclipse was an oversight and the ScalaTest guys have sent a release to the Scala IDE guys. Maybe we see it in the next milestone.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear and for the initiative ;]

Answer (score 2):

This is a version of the Scala IDE that works with Eclipse Luna (version 4.4).

http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/dev/site