# Install scalatest in Scala IDE Luna

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalatest, eclipse-luna

When installing only scalatest for the Scala IDE (Eclipse, Luna), by giving this update site:

http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/stable/site

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.icu,54.1.1.v201501272100
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.servlet,3.1.0.v201410161800
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.ant,1.9.4.v201504302020
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.core,3.4.0.v20150428-1928
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.launching,1.1.0.v20150428-1928
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ant.ui,3.6.0.v20150428-1928
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.compare,3.5.600.v20150420-1449
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.compare.core,3.5.500.v20150505-1058
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.commands,3.7.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.contenttype,3.5.0.v20150421-2214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.databinding,1.5.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans,1.3.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable,1.5.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.databinding.property,1.5.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.expressions,3.5.0.v20150421-2214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.filebuffers,3.5.500.v20140723-1040
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.filesystem,1.5.0.v20150421-0713
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7,1.0.100.v20150423-0754
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.jobs,3.7.0.v20150330-2103
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.net,1.2.300.v20141118-1725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.resources,3.10.0.v20150423-0755
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime,3.11.0.v20150405-1723
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility,3.2.300.v20150423-0821
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry,3.6.0.v20150318-1505
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.debug.core,3.10.0.v20150303-1130
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.debug.ui,3.11.0.v20150514-0917
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.commands,0.11.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts,1.4.0.v20150421-2214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.di,1.5.0.v20150421-2214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions,0.13.0.v20150421-2214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.services,2.0.0.v20150403-1912
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,0.11.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core,0.11.0.v20150511-1937
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt,0.12.0.v20150511-1003
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme,0.10.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.di,1.1.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,1.1.100.v20150407-1430
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,1.2.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets,1.1.0.v20150427-1751
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,1.3.0.v20150531-1948
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt,1.2.0.v20150512-1414
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,0.13.0.v20150603-0857
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,0.13.0.v20150504-0621
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench3,0.13.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.11.0.v20150512-0501
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.11.0.v20150512-0501
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,2.11.0.v20150512-0501
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.11.0.v20150512-0501
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.app,1.3.300.v20150423-1356
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.common,3.7.0.v20150402-1709
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.console,1.1.100.v20141023-1406
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.ds,1.4.300.v20150423-1356
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin,2.0.200.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox,1.0.600.v20150522-2234
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty,3.1.0.v20150323-1312
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet,1.2.0.v20150519-1816
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper,1.0.500.v20150119-1358
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.launcher,1.3.100.v20150511-1540
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64,1.1.300.v20150602-1417
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository,1.1.400.v20150513-2116
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.console,1.0.400.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core,2.4.0.v20150527-1706
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director,2.3.200.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director.app,1.0.400.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher,1.1.100.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine,2.4.0.v20150511-1532
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extensionlocation,1.2.200.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.jarprocessor,1.0.400.v20150430-1836
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata,2.3.0.v20150511-1532
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository,1.2.200.v20150428-1613
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations,2.4.100.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher,1.4.0.v20141117-0929
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse,1.2.0.v20150601-1708
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins,1.1.300.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository,2.3.100.v20150428-1613
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools,2.1.100.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse,2.1.300.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives,1.2.0.v20150519-1136
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf,1.1.100.v20150521-1342
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui,2.4.0.v20150425-0422
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport,1.1.100.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk,1.0.400.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler,1.2.100.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite,1.0.500.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.preferences,3.5.300.v20150408-1437
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.registry,3.6.0.v20150318-1503
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.security,1.2.100.v20150423-1356
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator,1.1.100.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.manipulator,2.0.100.v20150423-1455
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help.base,4.0.300.v20150603-2000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.help.webapp,3.7.0.v20150425-0643
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt,3.11.0.v20150603-2000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core,3.4.0.v20150518-1201
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core,1.1.0.v20150423-0947
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui,3.4.0.v20150423-0947
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt,1.2.0.v20150514-0146
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool,1.1.0.v20150513-2007
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.11.0.v20150602-1242
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation,1.5.100.v20141002-1241
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug,3.9.0.v20150528-1838
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui,3.7.0.v20150505-1916
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user,3.11.0.v20150603-1912
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit,3.8.0.v20150428-1340
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core,3.7.400.v20150423-0747
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime,1.1.500.v20150423-0747
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.launching,3.8.0.v20150527-0946
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.11.0.v20150527-0925
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.continuation,9.2.9.v20150224
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.http,9.2.9.v20150224
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.io,9.2.9.v20150224
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.security,9.2.9.v20150224
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.server,9.2.9.v20150224
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.servlet,9.2.9.v20150224
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.util,9.2.9.v20150224
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface,3.11.0.v20150602-1400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface.databinding,1.7.0.v20150406-2148
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jface.text,3.10.0.v20150603-1752
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jsch.core,1.2.0.v20141202-1415
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jsch.ui,1.2.0.v20141202-1415
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring,3.6.200.v20140826-0859
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring,3.7.200.v20140625-1835
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.osgi,3.10.100.v20150529-1857
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state,1.0.100.v20150402-1551
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.osgi.services,3.5.0.v20150519-2006
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.osgi.util,3.3.100.v20150423-1351
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde,3.11.0.v20150603-2000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.api.tools,1.0.700.v20150513-0819
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.api.tools.ui,1.0.600.v20150513-0819
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.build,3.9.100.v20150521-1524
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.core,3.10.100.v20150522-0332
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.doc.user,3.11.0.v20150603-1944
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.ds.core,1.0.400.v20150423-1241
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui,1.0.400.v20150506-1709
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime,3.4.500.v20150423-1241
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.launching,3.6.300.v20150423-1241
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.runtime,3.4.500.v20150423-1241
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.ua.core,1.0.400.v20150220-1252
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.ua.ui,1.0.400.v20150513-1136
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.ui,3.8.200.v20150602-2024
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates,3.5.0.v20150528-1349
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.platform,4.5.0.v20150603-2000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.platform.doc.user,4.5.0.v20150603-2358
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.rcp,4.5.0.v20150603-2000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.search,3.10.0.v20150318-0856
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.swt,3.104.0.v20150528-0211
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64,3.104.0.v20150528-0211
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.core,3.7.100.v20150203-1452
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.ui,3.7.200.v20150203-1452
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.text,3.5.400.v20150505-1044
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui,3.107.0.v20150507-1945
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.browser,3.4.300.v20150429-0602
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.console,3.6.0.v20150512-1341
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.editors,3.9.0.v20150213-1939
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.externaltools,3.3.0.v20150302-1002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.forms,3.6.200.v20150506-2029
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.ide,3.11.0.v20150510-1749
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.ide.application,1.1.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.intro,3.4.300.v20141007-1449
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal,3.2.800.v20150325-0952
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.navigator,3.6.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources,3.5.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.themes,1.1.0.v20150511-0913
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.trace,1.0.300.v20150220-1252
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.views,3.8.0.v20150422-0725
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.views.log,1.0.600.v20150513-1840
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed,3.6.100.v20150423-0822
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.win32,3.2.500.v20150423-0822
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.workbench,3.107.0.v20150510-1732
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor,3.9.100.v20141023-1946
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.junit,4.12.0.v201504281640
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations,1.4.0.v20150528-1451
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.emf.xpath,0.1.100.v20150513-0856
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.e4.rcp,1.4.0.v20150603-0857
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.e4.ui.dialogs,1.0.0.v20150513-0856
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.11.0.v20150512-0501
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.11.0.v20150512-0501
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature,1.3.100.v20150527-1706
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extras.feature,1.2.100.v20150601-1708
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.rcp.feature,1.2.100.v20150527-1706
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui,2.2.100.v20150601-1708
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.help,2.1.0.v20150603-2000
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.annotation,1.1.100.v20140704-0625
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.annotation,2.0.100.v20150311-1658
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jdt,3.11.0.v20150603-2000
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.pde,3.11.0.v20150603-2000
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.platform,4.5.0.v20150603-2358
No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.platform_root,4.5.0.v20150603-2358
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.rcp,4.5.0.v20150603-2331
No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.rcp_root,4.5.0.v20150603-2331
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.monitoring,1.0.0.v20150512-1436
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.tukaani.xz,1.3.0.v201308270617
```

Note that my config when clicking `Help > About`is the following:

```
Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK
Build id: 4.1.0-vfinal-20150525-1102-Typesafe
(c) LAMP/EPFL and Typesafe for Scala IDE and associated plugins
The Scala IDE for Eclipse provides an integrated environment for creating Scala programs.
Visit http://scala-ide.org/
...
```

I don't know where to start in this case. It may not be related to scalatest only since I cannot install many other plugins. Is this a Scala IDE restriction?

## what I've tried.

- [problem with installing plugins for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4672270/1287856) : but this is not Scala IDE
- [Error when updating eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/511367/1287856) : but adding a slash to the end of the website above did not work.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25731754/1287856 : Using this other link yields the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows > Preferences > Install/Update > Available software sites,
I included repositories containing each of the aforementionned packages found on the web, and it eventually worked.

Also, I unchecked the case in Help > Install new software
[image: Contact all update sites during install to find required software]